# VB.NET-Iteration through data table going out of bound

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, for-loop

i have been trying to iterate through two data table at once to compare them using nested for loop, but the outer loop keep going to out of the conditioned variable.

```
query_strg = "my query"
rs = New SqlCommand(query_strg, myconn)
adap.SelectCommand = rs
adap.Fill(dset)
count = dset.Rows.Count
For k = 0 To (count - 1)
    For j = 0 To (dset1.Rows.Count - 1)
    If (dset1.Rows(j)("name2").ToString() =dset.Rows(k)("name1").ToString() 
    OrElse (dset.Rows(k)("name2").ToString() = "General" 
    OrElse (dset.Rows(k)("name2").ToString() = "general" 
    OrElse (dset.Rows(k)("name2").ToString() = "Reports")))) Then
            dset.Tables(0).Rows(k).Delete()
            dset.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
            count = dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        End If
    Next j
Next k
```

This is my code.... The dset contain only single column and dset1 contain 5 columns. I need to compare a single column in dset1 to dset and if equal i need to delete that column and also i have performed other comparisons which are mandatory....

But the problem is the outer for loop goes out of bound resulting in one of the if conditions to throw exception as 'No row available at no.' something like that....

Need to know why the for loop goes out of bound and if there is not solution for it... I need an alternate idea to perform this action.

Comment: It could be that dset.Rows.Count returns a different value than dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count. Try starting from the outer limit (For K = count - 1) and work down as you are deleting.

Comment: Do you want to delete column or row? Can you post sample data and expected results

Comment: the count returns accurate value... And i need to delete rows from one of the table that is dset, and dset1 do not need any alteration......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ....

```
Dim dr, dr1 as DataRow

count = dset.tables(0).Rows.Count
For k = 0 To (count - 1)
    If k > dset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then Exit For

    dr = dset.tables(0).Rows(k)
    For j = 0 To (dset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)

        dr1 = dset1.tables(0).Rows(j) 
        If (dr1("name2").ToString() = dr("name1").ToString() 
        OrElse (UCase(dr("name2").ToString()) = "GENERAL"             
        OrElse (dr("name2").ToString() = "Reports")))) Then
            dset.Tables(0).Rows(k).Delete()
            dset.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
            count = dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count

        End If
    Next j
Next k
```

Comment: i am not going to compare values from different columns... Two tables have same column but dset has only tat column and dset1 has 5 columns, but both have the column which is 'Component name' is the one i need to compare.... and dset and dset1 may contain different number of rows.....

Comment: that's the problem... see the rows being deleted, so i think the count in outer for loop will not be updated after the changes so the loop throws exception....what to do there??

Comment: @user2536944 .. yes, your count var was fixed, so we have to recalculate in the loop .. try again ..

Comment: is the condition variable in for loop always be fixed... or can i use for condition like  For k = 0 To (dset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)...

Comment: @user2536944 .. `(dset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1` would be translated to any value before looping begin .. But I want to know wether you have try my answer ?

Comment: ya.... your answer works perfectly, thanks for ur time.... But i just need to know why for loop goes out of count variable when i update it after every changes......

Comment: @user2536944 .. So, dont forget to make a green tick below the downvote sign ( to make this as the answer ) .... :)